# Comenzar con Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Estoy iniciando en la creación de paginas web y mi pregunta es:

¿Cuál es la instalación mínima necesaria para comenzar a usar Bootstrap y crear sitios web responsivos?

He escuchado que se puede usar sin instalar el framework, ¿es esto verdad?

Comment: Hola @JoelBuenrostro, si lo que necesitas es un tutorial hay abundantes en español en la web. Luego puedes volver a preguntar cuando tengas un probema específico y con gusto alguien podrá ayudarte.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Opino que al menos su última pregunta, si se puede usar sin instalar, sí es aceptable para SO. ¿Estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: @ArturoTena el problema es que no existe tal cosa como *instalar* un framework. La pregunta denota poco conocimiento sobre programación web en general y va a ser de poca ayuda para otros usuarios. Lo mas recomendable es que Joel aprenda un poco más en algún buen tutorial y si tiene algún problema para entender alguna parte o para que funcione correctamente, cree otra pregunta específica sobre el problema exacto.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Bootstrap es un framework así que no es verdad. http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap/info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para usar boostrap solo necesitas tener referenciados en tu HTML los siguientes archivos:

- bootstrap.min.css
- bootstrap.min.js

Que se descargan desde el [sitio de bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download).

En caso de que uses glyphicons (los íconos que se usan), tendrías que copiar la carpeta fuente.

Como referencia puedes empezar por:

- http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
- http://getbootstrap.com/components

O si quieres empezar con una plantilla para ir modificándola y analizando su código, puedes ver algunos en el sitio http://startbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 2):

Si no quieres descargar el framework puedes hacer instancia usando el `CDN` y checando algunos ejemplos en la página oficial el `CDN` lo encuentras en la parte de [descargas](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) y los ejemplos en la sección de [componentes](http://getbootstrap.com/components/), saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Boostrap aunque es considerado un **framework** front-end, realmente son una seria de archivos **CSS** y **Javascript** que te ayudan a mejorar el aspecto visual y de usabilidad de tus proyectos.

Puedes descargarte esta serie de archivos desde el sitio oficial (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download), o bien, usar un manejador de paquetes como bower o npm.

Para descargarte el zip pasate por aquí:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.6/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist.zip

Answer (score 2):

Puede usar [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) que trae consigo muchas de las dependencias para crear proyectos front end con HTML5 y Bootstrap. En realidad es muy bueno